# Differences in calculation for Naive net in WEKA

Tags: weka, naivebayes

I tried out Naive net in weka 3.8 using weather dataset
Weka results

### OUTLOOK

Sunny Yes = 0.238
      No = 0.538

Overcast Yes = 0.429
         No = 0.077

Rainy Yes = 0.333
      No = 0.385

### TEMPERATURE

Hot Yes = 0.238
      No = 0.385

mild Yes = 0.429
         No = 0.385

Cool Yes = 0.333
      No = 0.231

But when I workedout it manually.My results are

### OUTLOOK

Sunny Yes (2/9)= 0.22
      No (3/5)= 0.60

Overcast Yes (4/9)= 0.44
         No (0/5)= 0

Rainy Yes (3/9)= 0.333
      No (2/5)= 0.40

### TEMPERATURE

Hot Yes (2/9)= 0.222
      No (2/5)= 0.40

mild Yes (4/9)= 0.444
         No (2/5)= 0.40

Cool Yes (3/9)= 0.333
      No (1/5)= 0.20

Why is this difference?
Whether my calculation went wrong somewhere?

Comment: What "But when I workedout it manually" means? You coded your own Naive Bayes algorithm?

Comment: I worked out in paper using the equations mentioned in Naive Bayes Algorithm

Comment: ok your results are close enough. Each algorithm is a bit different, some use smoothing functions, so small differences are normal. The fact that you have 0 for Outlook/Overcast and Weka provides 0.077 tells me that you don't apply such a smoothing while weka probably does (ex: Laplace smoothing)